# Application not running on API higher than 22

Tags: java, android, linux, ubuntu, android-emulator

Even if I create a new project I can't run it on API 23 and above. I have received only "waiting for target device to come online". Lower versions(22 and so on) work perfectly, they compile, run, I can create projects on them. I don't understand what could be the reason that for some API an empty project won't start.

I'm on Android Studio on Ubuntu. I tried basic solutions like updates, re-installing SDK Tools, e.t.c. I have tried on many emulators and versions. The amount of RAM is also not a problem.

What could be causing this behavior? what is the problem? How i can fix that?

Comment: can you show your max and min sdk version in your build gradle ?

Comment: @AlirezaHajigholamreza There you go: compileSdkVersion 30 | buildToolsVersion "30.0.3" | minSdkVersion 23 | targetSdkVersion 30. That's not working, if i run it on emulator API 23. But if i just change minSdkVersion to  22 and run it on emulator API 22, everything is fine.